# Get last observations from Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming the following dataframe:

```
        variable   value
0       A          12
1       A          11
2       B          4
3       A          2
4       B          1
5       B          4
```

I want to extract the last observation for each variable. In this case, it would give me:

```
        variable   value
3       A          2
5       B          4
```

How would you do this in the most panda/pythonic way?
I'm not worried about performance. Clarity and conciseness is important.

The best way I came up with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'variable': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'value': [12, 11, 4, 2, 1, 4]})
variables = df['variable'].unique()
new_df = df.drop(index=df.index, axis=1)
for v in variables:
    new_df = new_df.append(df[df['variable'] == v].tail(1), inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `drop_duplicates`

```
new_df = df.drop_duplicates('variable',keep='last')
Out[357]: 
  variable  value
3        A      2
5        B      4
```

Comment: Brilliant! This also preserves the order of the data frame. Unlike my attempt which has the side-effect of sorting on variable. (In order of appearance)